# His ring and her digits

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, letters

A young lady named Thea decided to change the traditional codes and asked her boyfriend to marry her at the Eiffel Tower.

As he loves puzzles, she said while showing him this text, "rightly choose two consonants that appear twice in this puzzle, select the right digits among the following list and you'll get a present from me <3."

- 00
- 01
- 10
- 14
- 41
- 62
- 72

He found the right digits then received his wedding ring. How did he succeed?

Comment: I *think* you have a typo "*she said while showing her this text*".

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct digits are:

> $0$ and $4$

Reasoning:

> The puzzle places emphasis on the *right* column by using *rightly* and *right*. Additionally, I believe that the mention of *Eiffel Tower* and *consommes* are intentional. *Consommes* is a French word that translates *consumes* in English.
>  Using [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking), we can evaluate if any matching numbers in the right column, when added together (e.g. consume each other), create a new number. $0$ and $0$ result in zero, so they stay broken apart. $1$ and $1$ becomes $2$ while $2$ and $2$ become $4$. After this process, we're left with $0$, $0$, $2$, $4$ and $4$.
>  Out of these, only $0$ and $4$ occur twice.
>  <sub>***Note**: I intentionally didn't apply multiple passes, which would break this answer.*</sub>

Comment: I +1 for the reasoning but actually "consommes" is a typo I made >< The right word is consonants